# How can I double check my use of Profile Tokens on the IBM iSeries?

Tags: security, ibm-midrange

I am using the IBM security APIs (QSYGENPT, QSYRMVPT, etc) to create profile tokens on an iSeries system when users authenticate in order to start jobs as the user.  There is a fixed limit of 2,000,000 such tokens that can be created on the system, so one needs be careful to delete any token created when it's no longer needed.  Failing to do so would constitute a leak of a critical system resource.

However, I can find no way on the system to report a current total count of the tokens, list tokens created by a particular job and/or user, or anything like that, so I have no way of validating that my program is not leaking tokens.

So far, the only way seems to be to use the system's audit journal entries and tediously match up token create/delete audit entries.  Ugh!

Can anyone offer any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fqsygenpt.htm) the maximum time a Profile Token is valid is 3600 seconds. I can't imagine any legitimate circumstance where a system would need to generate 2,000,000 Profile Tokens in an hour.  I mention this only to set your mind at ease - I don't think you need to worry about your program leaking resources!

I'm not aware of any way to list Profile Tokens but there's no reason you can't maintain your own list.

1) Create a table (physical file in iSeries parlance) to store token ID, user ID and datetime the token is created. Maybe the datetime it will expire as well if you create tokens with various lifetimes.

2) Call `QSYGENPT` API.

3) If successful, add a record to your table.

4) Have a job that runs periodically and looks at all the records in your table. Have it call the `QSYRMVPT` API if the current datetime is later than the expiration datetime of the Profile Token.

Then you'll know how many tokens are allocated, to whom and when they'll be expiring.

If the iSeries in question has a normal "nightly down time" where it does backups, patches or whatever you could call the [QsyRemoveAllPrfTkns API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fqsyrmapt.htm) and be sure that you've removed ALL the tokens so you'll have the full 2,000,000 to start with when the system comes back up.

Comment: "the maximum time a Profile Token is valid is 3600 seconds" - True, but the token can still be deleted with `QSYRMVPT` after it's expired.  Furthermore you call call `QSYRMVPT` exactly once on any given token, expired or not, strongly implying that expiry does not equate to deletion.

Comment: True. However if you keep track of the tokens you allocate as I suggested you can wait until after their 3600 lifetime (or whatever you set it to be) and then delete them - then you would know for sure that they are not being used and that they are deleted.

I don't know this for certain but I bet that if a token is not deleted when it expires then it is marked as "deleted" so it can be reused - very much like a record in a physical file with reuse deleted records = *YES doesn't actually delete the record, it only marks it as "deleted" for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: Just FTR, you would have lost your bet. Timing out does not remove the tokens; only QSYRMVPT et al. If they are not deleted they take up one of the slots and the system does nothing to recover them.  And there's no API to remove expired tokens.  Truly the worst implementation of such a facility I could have imagined.

Comment: Well, as the casinos in Las Vegas are well aware - I've lost plenty of bets :-) Back on topic: that truly is a horrible implementation and I would have expected better from IBM.